# Netbeans 6.9.1 Database Empty Nodes

Tags: java, database, nodes

I'm a java developer who used Netbeans 6.8 previously and running all of the projects without any problems. Only today, I tried to use Netbeans 6.9.1 and getting my Database Node empty.

How to solve it anyway?
[Preview1.](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/6219/databasenodeempty.jpg)
[Preview2.](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9324/netbeans691exception.png)

I tried to google but found no solutions. CMIIW.

Comment: What version did you install? The Java one, the full one? Did you import the setting from 6.8? Oh, and one more? Teh DB drivers should be in your Netbeans installation in the folder `ide\modules\ext`. Are they there?

Comment: it is the Full one... 
NB 6.9.1 version... 
Drivers? you mean jar files or something?

Comment: @madth3 I already opened that directory, And found this screenshot: 
http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/120/idemodulesext.jpg
is that a problem over there? What files are required to use Netbeans Database node to be available? :(

Comment: The drivers for mysql and postgresql seem to be where they should. As @Krishan points out, this seems like a bug. If you are using Java 7 you could go back to 1.6 or maybe trying going all the way to NB 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is now solved.
The Netbeans 6.8 and Netbeans 6.9.1 are not having bugs at all.
THe cause that made this symptomp is because of the JDK 7 update 1.

So, I uninstall everything(Netbeans & JDK 7), and reinstall back (Netbeans with JDK 6 latest update) And now problem's solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the database node and either click "New Connection" or if you have installed mysql click "Register MySQL Server".

Comment: I did, I already have mysql first before installing NB.
But the Database Node is always empty. If I tried to right click, It generate the error, please look at the picture Preview 1 above. :(

Comment: Did you try reinstalling netbeans? This may be a problem with the installation

Comment: sure, I did reinstalling it back. And found the same thing, Is there any kind of options to enabled them or something? :(

Comment: I think it is a bug. See [this](http://statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/exception.do?id=509413)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this uninstalling Netbeans 6.9.1 and jdk 7 and reinstalling **jdk 1.6** and Netbeans 6.9.1 again.