# Can anyone tell me why Database options in my netbeans 6.8 seems empty?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans6.8

Can anyone tell me why Database options under services in my netbeans 6.8 seems empty with no options.
Before installing netbeans 6.8 i've also installed netbeans 7.1 also in my operating system. In netbeans 7.1 i've all database option, but why i'm not getting that under netbeans 6.8?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCHiL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer, but the following link is talking about this issue

[Netbeans 6.9.1 Database Empty Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236765/netbeans-6-9-1-database-empty-nodes)

Read it **carefully**, and apply the solution only if it is related to you.